# ¿Por qué esta función no funciona?

Tags: c++, double, float

La función cuantosDecimalesTiene() funciona con la mayoría de números (0.3 , 6.66 , 6.66664) pero con otros no (4.44 , 6.666, 345.345543). **¿Por qué? Gracias**.

```cpp
bool esEntero(double x){//Devuelve true si x es entero, false si no lo es. esEntero(3.23) = false
    int y = x;
    //El número es duplicado y su copia es truncada
    return !(y-x);
    //Si y-x es 0, significa que el numero no ha cambiado al truncarse, por tanto es entero
}

unsigned int cuantosDecimalesTiene(double numero){

    /*Esta función devuelve el número de decimales del parámetro. cuantosDecimales(3.23) = 2
    Para ello multiplica el parámetro por 10 hasta que este sea entero
    El número de veces que haya sido necesario multiplicar por 10 (el exponente de 10) es el número de decimales. */

    unsigned int i{}; //Un numero de decimales es entero y positivo. Ej. 3 decimales, 4 decimales...
    while(!esEntero(numero)){ //Si el número aún no es entero, hay que volver a multiplicarlo por 10.
        numero *= 10;
        i++; //Se ha multiplicado por 10 una vez más.
        //cout << i << endl; Descomentar para ver el progreso
    }
    return i; //El número de decimales de un número es las veces que hay que multiplicarlo por 10 para que sea entero.
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El tipo `double` no es matemáticamente equivalente a un número real. No puede serlo, porque el conjunto de los reales es infinito (más que infinito, podría decirse, pues sólo entre 0 y 1 ya hay infinitos reales), mientras que el tipo `double` tiene sólo 64 bits y por tanto sólo puede representar 2^64 números diferentes en el mejor de los casos (en realidad menos porque ciertas combinaciones se reservan para representar conceptos especiales, como "infinito" o "NaN").

Esto conlleva que hay números que no pueden representarse con un `double`. De hecho, hay un número infinito de ellos.

Los que sí pueden representarse de forma exacta son los que son potencia de dos (tales como 2^-1, 2^-2, etc.) o sumas de potencias de dos. Así, el 0.5, el 0.25 o el 0.75 serían representables de forma exacta en un `double`. Pero números de aspecto tan inocente como 0.1 ó 0.2 no son potencia de dos, y por tanto no son representables en este formato. Lo que guarda el computador es el representable más próximo (dentro de un cierto número de decimales).

En definitiva, los números con los que has probado no son representables de forma exacta. El 4.44 por ejemplo, si lo "miras bien" verás que en realidad es almacenado como:

```
4.44000000000000039079850466805510222911834716796875
```

que es la suma de potencias de dos más próxima a 4.44 que puede encontrarse, dada la precisión del formato. Para obtener este dato he hecho `printf("%60.f", 4.44)` para verlo con 60 decimales (aunque la cantidad de decimales a mostrar varía con el número, si el número es grande, se guardan menos decimales y si es menor que 1 se pueden guardar más, pues lo que es fijo es por así decir la cantidad de dígitos, dentro de los cuales se coloca después la coma, por eso lo de "coma flotante").

Esa es la explicación de que no funcione tu algoritmo con el 4.44

### Más sorpresas

Pero es que ¡tampoco el 0.3, el 6.66 o el 6.66664 son suma de potencias de dos, por lo que tampoco son representables! El 6.66 de hecho se almacena como:

```
6.660000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625
```

entonces la verdadera pregunta sería **¿Por qué funcionó tu algoritmo con ciertos números**, cuando lo esperable sería que no hubiera funcionado con prácticamente ninguno? Es difícil dar por azar con un número que sea suma de potencias de dos, pero rápidamente puedes ver cuándo no lo es, si el último decimal no es 5 (que sea 5 tampoco es garantía, por ejemplo 0.05 no es potencia de 2).

Para descubrir cómo es que el 6.66 te funcionó, puedes modificar `esEntero(x)` para que imprima su argumento, en cada iteración:

```
bool esEntero(double x){esEntero(3.23) = false
    int y = x;

    printf("x=%.60f\n", x);
    return !(y-x);
    //Si y-x es 0, significa que el numero no ha cambiado al truncarse, por tanto es entero
}
```

Entonces, al ejecutar el programa para `x=6.66` vemos que se detiene tras tres iteraciones, y que los valores de `x` son:

```
x=6.660000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625000000000000
x=66.599999999999994315658113919198513031005859375000000000000000
x=666.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

¡Ha sido casualidad! Ya que no todos los números son representables, el procesador matemático se ve obligado a, tras cada operación, redondear el resultado a la suma de potencias de dos más próxima. Esto es, en cada operación hay un error de redondeo. La primera multiplicación por 10, por ejemplo, en lugar de dar `66.6000000000000014210854715202003717422485351562500000000000`, que sería lo correto (pero no es representable) ha dado `66.599999999999994315658113919198513031005859375`, que es incorrecto pero representable. Al multiplicar a su vez por 10 este valor, debería haber dado `665.99999999999994315658113919198513031005859375, pero de nuevo no es representable y se ha cambiado por`666.0`, que es el representable más próximo, y que **casualmente** tiene todo 0 en la parte fracción y por eso tu algoritmo se detiene.

Esta afortunada casualidad no tiene por qué producirse con otros números, en los que el redondeo a un número cuya parte-fracción sea todo 0 puede ocurrir en cualquier otro momento posterior (o no ocurrir nunca, salvo porque se llegue a un número tan grande, a base de multiplicar por 10, que ya no haya sitio en el formato para la parte fracción).

### Solución

Como te han comentado, la solución típica a estos problemas cuando se trabaja con `float` o `double` consiste en nunca comparar *directamente* una variable con otra, sino conformarse con decir que su diferencia sea inferior a un cierto *epsilon* que es la máxima precisión con la que nos limitaremos a trabajar.

Así, tu función debería ser cambiada a esta forma:

```
#define EPSILON 1e-10   // aprox 10 decimales

bool esEntero(double x){//Devuelve true si x es entero, false si no lo es. esEntero(3.23) = false
    int y = x;
    return !(x-y > EPSILON);
    //Si y-x es muy pequeño, significa que el numero no ha cambiado al truncarse, por tanto es entero
}
```

Otro enfoque podría ser convertir el `double` en una cadena (usando `sprintf()` y después contar cuántos dígitos hay tras el punto, hasta encontrarnos con una secuencia de ceros de una longitud "suficiente" (habría que definir esto también, de forma más o menos arbitraria, pues ¿vas a usarlo con números como `4.440000002`?). Considero que este enfoque podría ser mejor, al evitar los sucesivos errores de redondeo en cada multiplicación por 10.

La moraleja es: un `double` no es un real. Atento a las sorpresas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Sabrías decirme que epsilon debería usar en algunos casos? Gracias!

Answer (score 3):

No funciona por la forma en la que funcionan los números en [coma flotante](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coma_flotante).

Los números enteros `int`, `long`, se pueden almacenar en binario puro, en complemento a dos o alguna lógica similar que no altera el número en ningún caso. Sin embargo los números en coma flotante se normalizan. Esto quiere decir que se suelen representar como 1.X^Y o 0.X^Y. Esta normalización conlleva divisiones y las divisiones de números binarios puede generar secuencias infinitas. Como el equipo no dispone de un campo de longitud infinita para representar el número, la secuencia se trunca y ahí se pierde un poco de información. Por eso, los números en coma flotante no tienen una precisión plena sino relativa. Prueba de ello es que los números `float` tienen una precisión de 6 dígitos mientras que `double` tiene una precisión de 12 dígitos.

Así, lo que para ti es una operación obvia:

```
int y = x;
return !(x-y);
```

A nivel binario no lo es tanto. Aquellos números que han generado una secuencia infinita, al truncarse resulta en un número muy muy parecido al original... pero no es el mismo. Así las operaciones posteriores darán resultados muy parecidos a los esperados pero con una ligerísima diferencia en los últimos bits del número.

Esos últimos bits, son capaces de modificar los decimales que se quedan fuera de la precisión antes comentada (6 para `float` y 12 para `double`), luego cuando el procesador hace las comparaciones el resultado es que los dos números no son binariamente idénticos.

Los números en coma flotante se deben comparar con umbrales. Nunca con comparaciones directas.

Debido a todo esto, es relativamente complicado saber cuántos dígitos tiene un número en coma flotante. De hecho, en cuanto el número genere una secuencia binaria infinita o lo suficientemente larga como para no entrar en la variable, podrás dar por imposible saber cuántos dígitos tenía el número original, ya que ese número se ha modificado al no ser posible su almacenamiento en la variable).

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Esta parece una pregunta similar a [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843999/calculate-number-of-decimal-places-for-a-float-value-without-libraries). En resumen en vez de comparar que la diferencia entre y-x sea 0 deberias utilizar un 'umbral' dependiendo de la cantidad de numeros decimales que quieres conseguir, esto es debido que al realizar

```cpp
int y = x;
```

Es posible que se este truncando en vez de redondear lo que seria lo adecuado, en el enlace que te comparti hablan mas en detalle sobre la causa de tu problema.