# ¿Qué diferencia entre float y double en C++?

Tags: c++, float, double, tipos

estoy aprendiendo los tipos de datos en C++ y tengo una duda. ¿Qué diferencia entre float y double en C++?

Sé que la precisión es doble en el caso del double, no la aprecio en la salida de la consola.
También sé que float puede albergar 7 dígitos (¿en decimales o el número entero más los decimales?) y que double puede 15.

Pues eso, no les veo la diferencia a la hora de probarlos en la consola.

```
float numeroFloat = 569.64895769;
double numeroDouble = 569.64895769;

cout << numeroFloat << endl;
cout << numeroDouble;
```

La salida es la misma en ambos casos:

569.649

569.649

Comment: El tamaño en memoria de cada uno de esos tipos es diferente. `float` ocupa 32 bits mientras que `double` ocupa 64 bits. Esto afecta a la cantidad de números diferentes que "caben" en cada uno de estos formatos. En `double` se pueden almacenar números más grandes y también más decimales. Con los números que has probado no se ve diferencia porque `cout <<` redondea la representación interna para mostrar pocos decimales, y lo que ves en ambos casos es lo mismo, pero internamente no son iguales. Si pudieras imprimirlos con muchos más decimales (no sé cómo se hace en C++) verías que son diferentes.

Comment: [Esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/165189/7123) puede iluminarte, y [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/276344/7123) también es relevante aunque sea C y  no C++

Comment: Como te lo han explicado quizas de igual manera te puede interesar que para el uso de sistemas que conlleven un conteo bancario en JAVA se usa el BigDecimal, no es primitivo es una clase externa pero que ayuda a no generar posibles perdidas de centavos por el uso de tipos de datos como "float" o "double"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La diferencia entre **double** y **float** esta dada en 2 aspectos claves q es la diferencia en su tasa de bits mientras q **float** q usa **32 bits** puede almacenar cerca alrededor de *7 decimales* el **double** de **64 bits** almacena hasta *15 dígitos*, además q la hora de procesar números *infinitos* o de gran tamaño hay un gran margen de error si los calculas usando **float** por supuesto hay números tan grandes q ni si quiera el **double** acepta y es cuando hay q recurrir a los **long double** lo q notar una diferencia fuera de esto es algo difícil dado q el resultado *exacto* de estos decimales puede verse **afectado** por el **auto redondeo** del IDE q uses.

Comment: ¡Perfecto! Visual Studio 2022, estaba haciendo redondeo así como quería (me saca por defecto 2 decimales, por muchos que tenga el float o el double). Lo tengo en cuenta.

Comment: El único detalle es que el tipo `long double` compilado con MSVC, se implementa de la misma manera que `double`, siendo equivalentes. Así que si quieres mayor precisión toca cambiar de compilador.

Answer (score 2):

Ambos tipos de datos permiten codificar números reales.

Las únicas diferencias son que los literales de `float` se escriben con un punto y una `f` al final. Por ejemplo `1.0f`. Y que  `double` tiene más precisión que `float` por ende ocupa más memoria.

Quizá te resulte útil:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Answer (score 0):

Primero, te respondo tu pregunta: la precisión es el resultado de la suma de los números enteros más los decimales.
Segundo si deseas que cout no te limite la cantidad de valores a mostrar en pantalla debe incluir la librería  y luego debes poner cout << setpresicion(16);
Si después muestras los valores te darás cuenta que el float te garantiza 7 valores de precisión mientras que el double 15, aunque en tu caso te garantizará los 11 que tiene el numero que empleaste 569.64895769.
Espero que te sirva

Comment: La librería <iomanip>